# Concrete5 Pagination only working when logged in

Tags: caching, content-management-system, pagination, blogs, concrete5

I don't know if this is a caching issue or what, but when I click my pagination links (numbers or prev/next), the page seems to reload, but the page doesn't change. If I log in and do the same, it works exactly as expected.

I've turned off full page caching on my "News" page (the page with the Page List and Pagination on it), but the problem remains.

You can try it yourself here: http://tinyurl.com/k3kz2lc

I never noticed this until now, and the website has been live for a few months. I'm not sure if it was always this way or not.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sort this out I had to *turn off Block Caching*. It seems to work as expected with both Full Page Caching (If blocks on the particular page allow it) and Overrides Cache turned on.

Comment: This also worked for me for a seemingly unrelated problem: I developed a custom block that would sometimes refuse to load the `view.css` and `view.js` files: I turned off Block Caching and now both files show up when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what exactly the problem is without poking around in the block and the rest of the site.

However, the new full page caching in 5.6.2 frequently causes a lot of issues like this one. It wasn't built very intelligently.

I'm not very familiar with the fine-grain controls (ie, per-page), so can't help you out there. But to test, you should completely turn off all caching in your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions James. I played around with the different caching options and ended up getting it sorted out. Answer posted below.